# How to keep the URL same for the whole Website directory using .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Thanks in advance for any help that is provided.

The question is in the Title. To explain I would expand as follows:

When I go to `example.com/my/` **(*my* is a Directory, which has an `index.html` file)**
the URL should remain `example.com/my/`.

And, when I go to `example.com/my/anotherfile.php`, the URL should then too remain `example.com/my/`.

***Extra Note:*** The redirect to  `/anotherfile.php` is through a Form: `<form action="anotherfile.php"></form>`, so it won't be shown until someone inspects the Source.

**EDIT**

Since some people are not able to get what I mean to say, here's a different explanation:

I want people to browse my whole website `example.com` but the URL should remain `example.com` And I need it through .htaccess and not through iframes (can't explain why)

Comment: you can use frame set. or iframe for doing your requirement.. but those won't be SEO friendly.

Comment: Yup, IK that's why I asked for an "htaccess" solution.

Comment: but having multiple pages all showing as the exact same address is ALSO not SEO friendly.

Comment: Don't know about that. Anyway I needed an htaccess solution, since adding iframe just spoils the whole source. An htaccess solution if you have it would be much appreciated

Comment: Why not just have the index.php page that loads the content dynamically as the user navigates - use `$_POST` or `$_SESSION` variables to determine where someone is.

Comment: I don't understand `The redirect to /anotherfile.php is through a Form: <form action="anotherfile.php"></form>`. Is the form with target action `anotherfile.php` inside `anotherfile.php`???

Comment: @HermanNz Nope the target file `anotherfile.php` is seperate. It exists in the directory `example.com/my/`

Comment: @GeoffAtkins Can you explain??

Comment: it doesn't need htaccess to do that, you can use `header: location` or `meta refresh` then. otherwise, place all codes in `anotherfile.php` into index file in `my` directory.

Comment: @HermanNz `anotherfile.php` is not just a PHP file. It also has HTML content in it. Can you respond in regard with the Update. Thanks.

Comment: If you have an index.html file in that directory, going to the directory without any file extension on it will load that by default.  What you would need to do is route everything through one file within that directory, and get that file to load the required file.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that this is impossible.

The only way to give the appearance of multiple documents having the same URL is to load a document that actually has that URL and then modify what the user sees (e.g. by loading a different document in a frame, or using JavaScript to modify the content).

You can't use `.htaccess` for this because `.htaccess` is just a means to configure the server.

When the browser says "Please give me `/my/`" then the server has to respond with something. All it has to go on is `/my/` so it has no way of knowing if it should return the results of running `index.php` or `anotherfile.php`.

Answer (score 1):

To manage your whole site through a single URL, it's simplest to have a single page `index.php` and a load of content held in other files loaded as includes, as the user navigates through the site send a variable back to `index.php` either through `$_POST` or `$_SESSION` that loads new content, best practice would be to use `include` to keep our code tidy.

In this example we'll send the variable through `$_GET` and then reload the content with that variable stored in a `$_SESSION` variable.

The link would look like this:

```
<a href="?page=about">About</a>
```

Which would then trigger a condition at the top of the page and load that page.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
        $_SESSION['page'] = $_GET['page'];

        //This redirect removes the $_GET string so you are keeping the user on the same URL.
        header("Location: http://example.com/my/");
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['page'])) {
        include($_SESSION['page'] . '.php');
    } else {
        //Show home page content.
    }
```

You could streamline this process using JS, but this is an example of a pure PHP method.

Do bear in mind this will have some negative connotations for your SEO - although the `$_GET` variables means that search engines may be able to spider your site correctly, it will be confusing to end users. Only use this if you **really really** have to have a single front facing URL.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. That Looks like something I can use as this is something that wouldn't mess up my Source. :)

Comment: Although I do think there might be a `.htaccess` solution. As I have seen some good "Silent re-direct" rules by User @anubhava

Comment: Not really. You'd be able to hide the string into something prettier and even more search engine friendly, but you can't do it purely through `htaccess` and have different content on the same URL.